# Can't install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio

When I'm trying to install Visual Studio, it shows an error. It says

> Windows Installer package: vs_setup.msi could not be opened.

What should I do?

Comment: Where did you get the installer? Do other MSIs work?

Comment: @Nisha - We need the error log

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing from a compressed `.iso` image file or executable file to download over the internet? Are you sure there is no other installation going on in the background?

- If you'e installing from a compressed image using a virtual drive try closing and reopening the drive. If that doesn't work, then uncompress it and try again.
- If you're installing from an optical disc, then get another one, the disk may be corrupted.
- If you're using an executable file `.exe` try restarting your computer and try again.
- If the above doesn't work, check if there is a previous installation on your computer and uninstall then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the package and press "Run as Administrator" It could be a permissions issue.

Make sure you are not trying to open the package from a compressed folder (.zip, .7z, etc)

Also do you have the .NET framework installed?